# Excel crashes when running a loop to disable controls

Tags: vba, excel

```
Public Sub OptionsDisable()

    Dim myControls As CommandBarControls
    Dim ctl As CommandBarControl
    Dim iArray(21, 3181, 292, 3125, 855, 1576, 293, 541, 3183, 294, 542, 886, 887, 883, 884) As Long
    Dim myElement As Variant

    For Each myElement In iArray
        Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
            (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=myElement)
        If Not myControls Is Nothing Then
            For Each ctl In myControls
                ctl.Enabled = False
            Next ctl
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Okay everyone, when I run this subroutine, Excel just crashes.  I am trying to run through a loop to disable every control id in the array.  I'm thinking what is happening is it is entering an infinite loop, but I set a breakpoint on the first line with a for statement, and it still crashes, before it gets to there.  So, my other guess is it's a problem with my array and or variant defining.

Anyone have an idea?

P.S. Running this code will crash your Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub OptionsDisable()

Dim myControls As CommandBarControls
Dim ctl As CommandBarControl
Dim iArray As Variant
Dim myElement As Variant

iArray = Array(21, 3181, 292, 3125, 855, 1576, 293, 541, 3183, 294, 542, 886, 887, 883, 884)

    For Each myElement In iArray
        Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
            (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=myElement)
        If Not myControls Is Nothing Then
            For Each ctl In myControls
                ctl.Enabled = False
            Next ctl
        End If
    Next myElement

End Sub
```

When you `Dim` an array like this: `iArray(5)`, you're not creating an array with a single element `5`. You're basically creating an upper bound limit of items to put inside the array. When you start doing `iArray(x,y,z)`, you're confusing Excel and asks it to create a LOT of dimensions with insane upper bounds.

Basically, you were creating arrays wrong. The above should work. Alternatives like `Split` should as well. :)

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
Public Sub OptionsDisable1()

    Dim myControls As CommandBarControls
    Dim ctl As CommandBarControl
    Dim iArray As Variant
    Dim myElement As Variant

    iArray = Array(21, 3181, 292, 3125, 855, 1576, 293, 541, 3183, 294, 542, 886, 887, 883, 884)

    For Each myElement In iArray
        Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
            (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=myElement)
        If Not myControls Is Nothing Then
            For Each ctl In myControls
                ctl.Enabled = False
            Next ctl
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When you're using `Dim iArray(21, 3181, 292, 3125, 855, 1576, 293, 541, 3183, 294, 542, 886, 887, 883, 884) As Long` Excel doesn't initialize array with values as you expect, but tries to create array with 15 dimmensions

Comment: ...that's one huge array! If it could be created it would hold a total of `4*10^42` variables of type `Long` (8 bytes each).